# Search a word boundary at a length and replace it with '|'

Tags: regex, sas

I have a long string of more than 600 characters. I want to replace a word boundary at a length just less than 200 with "|".

I have used following code to do so. But I didi not have any luck.

```
data test;
   length str1 $200;
   str1 = "N=dddddd dddddd dddddd dddddddddd ddd ddddd dddddddd dd d ,n=,|t:14.2.2-1";
run;

data test1;
   set test;
   str01 = prxchange('s/\b/|/', -1, str1);
   str02 = prxchange('s/(.{20,}?\b).*/|/', -1, str1);
run;
```

I knew that the first one will search for all word boundaries and replace them with '|', but I thought second one would work. But the later gave me only '|' as the output.

What I am looking for is to break a long footnote (more than 600 chars) to be broken down in 4 line statements, because line can not have more than 200 char. So I will replace the space at a length no more than 200 with '|' and break the string down using the '|'

Thanks in Advance!

In real time scenario, I have following situation.

```
data test;
   length str1 $200;
   str1 = "XX XX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX XXX XXXXX X XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XX XXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX'X XXXXXX. XXXX XXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX. XXX XXXXXXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX XXX XX XXXX XX XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXXXX XXX XXX XXXXX XX XXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX 11112525 65, XX XXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXX XXX XXX. XXXXXXXXXXXX, XXX XXXX XXXXX XXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XX "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX" XX XXX XXX XXXXXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXXX. XXXX XX XX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXX. XXXXXXX, XXX XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XX "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX - XX XXX XXXXXXX" XXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXX XXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX X XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXX XXXXX.  XXXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX X XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX, X XXXX XXX XXXX XX XXXXXX XXXXX, XXXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XX XXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXXX XX XXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX. XXXX, XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XX XXXX XXXXX XXX XXXXXX) XXXX XXXXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXX "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX - XX XXX XXXXXXX/XX XXXXXXXXXX".  XXX XXXX XX XXX XXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX XXXXXXXXX XXXX XX XXXXXXX XX XXXXXX.  XXX XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXX XXXXX XX XXXX XXXX, XXX XXX XXXXX XXXX XX XXXXXX XXXX XX X XXXXXXXXX.";
run;
```

As suggested, I've used:

```
data test1;
   set test;
   str01 = prxchange('s/(.{200,}?)\b\s*/\1|/', -1, compbl(str1));
run;
```

But, it is not placing pipe at a word boundry at a length less than or equal to 200 characters. It is placing pipe just above 200. i.e. the expression is going forword ( above 200) rather backword (before or at 200) to place the pipe.

Kindly let me know what we are missing in the regular expression.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for promt help! Both gave the same results, and nearset to what I wanted. Nearest because it replaces a space with | and space. is there a way to not have space besides | Also it should not give | where there is already a |. Also, could you please elaborate on your solution on what $0 or $1 does? Can we have conditional search and replace i.e. search and replace only if the length is more than 200? Thanks once again!

Comment: I removed the comment since I gave an answer. As for **what $0 or $1 does?**, I think I clarified that in the answer below. I will update my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'s/(.{20,}?\b).*/|/'` replaces the whole string with no newlines (as it has optional `.{20,}?` and `.*`) and 1 word boundary with the replacement string (`\b`). Also, you capture text with `(...)` but you are not using it. You can use back-references to "restore" the captured text in the replaced result.

You need to remove `.*` at least and use the back-reference in the replacement string:

```
str02 = prxchange('s/(.{20,}?\b)/$1|/', -1, str1);
                               ^ ^^
```

Adjust the number in the limiting quantifier (`{20,}`) as necessary.

You can also get rid of the capturing group and use `\0` as back-reference to the whole matched text:

```
str02 = prxchange('s/.{20,}?\b/\0|/', -1, str1);
```

**UPDATE**

> is there a way to not have space besides `|` Also it should not give `|` where there is already a `|`.

Just use a negative look-behind (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ7yY6/1)):

```
.{20,}?\b(?![\w|])
```

> Can we have conditional search and replace i.e. search and replace only if the length is more than `200`?

We can, but it will look ugly. I suggest checking the string length first, and if the condition is met, proceed with the replacement:

```
if length(str1) > 200 then 
    str02 = prxchange('s/.{200,}?\b(?![\w|])/\0|/', -1, str1);
```

> Back-references

You can read more about [regex back-references at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html). Here is an excerpt:

> If your regular expression has named or numbered capturing groups, then you can reinsert the text matched by any of those capturing groups in the replacement text. Your replacement text can reference as many groups as you like, and can even reference the same group more than once. This makes it possible to rearrange the text matched by a regular expression in many different ways.

**UPDATE2**

Now, it seems you also need to "merge" words (remove whitespace) on both sides of `|`. Then, just use the following regex:

```
(.{20,}?)\b\s*
```

And replace with `\1|`.

Comment: @ stribizhev When I used the code  str02 = prxchange('s/.{200,}?\b(?![\w|])/\0|/', -1, str1); I am not getting the entire string with replaces '|' as needed. Instead it gives  "N=dddddd dddddd dddddd| dddddddddd ddd ddddd| dddddddd dd d ,n=,|t|:14.2.2-1" (with spaces and an extra | after t) instead of N=dddddd dddddd dddddd|dddddddddd ddd ddddd|dddddddd dd d ,n=,|t:14.2.2-1.

Comment: One thing is certain: the `|` before the `t:14` is already there. If you want to get rid of them, remove all `|` first. To solve the second issue, use `prxchange('s/(.{20,}?)\b\s*/\1|/', -1, str1);`. The result is `N=dddddd dddddd dddddd|dddddddddd ddd ddddd|dddddddd dd d ,n=,|t|:14.2.2-1`. Again, you cannot just remove existing and add some new characters with 1 operation only.

Comment: @ stribizhev I tried this regular expression on one of the real time scenarios. But the | is not getting placed at and just above 200 characters. I needed to have a | at 200 character or at a word boundry not exceeding 200 length. Can you please help on this situation.

Comment: Try `s/.{0,20}\b/\0|/`.

Comment: @ stribizhev Thanks! I Tried the expression, but it gives only .  ".  .  .". I've used  "regxfot3 = prxchange('s/.{0,200}\b/\0|/', -1, str1);" Kindly look at the updated question.

Comment: I see, the problem is with the limiting quantifier, it was `{20,}` = 20 or more. Now, I suggest using a `{1,20}` (or `{1,200}`) to match either 1 or 20(0) symbols. Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB7vB0/1).

Comment: @ stribizhev Thanks! Itried this option. The best solutionI got using  regxfot3 = prxchange('s/(.{1,200})\s\s*/\1|/', -1, compbl(DVTERM)); but it gives me | even at the end of the string. Also, when I use \0, it give only | and removes all other characters.

Comment: I do not know if a look-ahead is supported, maybe you can tell the regex engine to make sure there is at least some characters after the current match. Like [`(.{1,200})\b\s*(?=.{3})`](https://regex101.com/r/eB7vB0/2).